# What does a negative superscript mean on a positive Integer number

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, constructive-mathematics

I am reading ***Foundations of Constructive Analysis*** by Errett Bishop.  In the first chapter he describes a particular construction of the real numbers.  There is a intermediate definition before his primary introduction of the Real numbers:

> A sequence ${\{x_n\}}$ of rational numbers is regular if
>
> $|x_m - x_n | \le m^{-1} + n^{-1}\;\;\;\;\;(m, n\in \Bbb Z^+)$
>
> *Chapter 1 (2.1)*

What does the negative superscript mean in this definition?  Since clearly you cannot take an integer to a negative power.  Am I correct in interpreting $m$ and $n$ on the right hand side of the equation as the actual elements of the sequence? I am fairly sure the definition seems to parallel the Cauchy Sequence.

Comment: Did I miss something here? $m^{-1} = 1/m.$ And I wouldn't take that to be the same as $x_m. \qquad$

Comment: You should understand $m^{-1}$ as the fraction $1/m$ when $m$ is a positive integer.

Comment: "clearly you cannot take an integer to a negative power" Huh? Yes you can - you just get a non-integer as a result.

Comment: Who says you cannot take an integer to a negative power?  (the result may be in $\mathbb Q$, not necessarily in $\mathbb Z$)

Comment: Ok yeah that makes a lot sense, symbols man.  I will accept an answer, if anyone posts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm.... $m^{-1} = \frac{1}{m}$    ........

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
m^{-1} + n^{-1}= \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{m+n}{mn}.
$$
So we *can* take an integer to a negative power, namely as $n^{-k}=\frac{1}{n^k}$. And can we use the complex number $i$
 as an exponent?  We sure can. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html).